# Add Views to LinearLayout of Fragment everytime I click button

Tags: java, android, view, addition

I have a button, in `onClickListener` I have:

```
Button button1 = new Button(mContext);

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams x = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 button1.setLayoutParams(x);
 ll.addView(button1);
```

It works when I click first time the button, second click (and more) the button desn't add new button. Can somebody help me?

This is my class:

```
public class ListaDruzynAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private ArrayList<Druzyna>listaDruzyn;
private Context mContext;
private SelectedTeamsFragment selectedTeamsFragment=null;
private LinearLayout ll;
int i = 0;
public ListaDruzynAdapter(Context c,ArrayList lista){
    super(c, 0, lista);
    this.mContext = c;
    listaDruzyn=lista;
   ll=(LinearLayout)((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.selectedTeamFrag);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listaDruzyn.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    if (position==0){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24dp);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DodajNowaDruzyneFragment dodajNowaDruzyneFragment = new DodajNowaDruzyneFragment();
                dodajNowaDruzyneFragment.setListeDruzyn(ListaDruzynAdapter.this);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
                dodajNowaDruzyneFragment.show(fragmentManager,"ADD_NEW_TEAM_FRAGMENT");
            }
        });
    }else{
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_24dp);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedTeamsFragment==null){
                    selectedTeamsFragment = new SelectedTeamsFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction ft=((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(R.id.selectedTeamFrag,selectedTeamsFragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }

                    Button button1 = new Button(mContext);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams x = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    button1.setLayoutParams(x);
                    ll.addView(button1);

            }
        });
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

}

Class is an adapter where first item in gridd is "add" buttons. Added buttons are adding new one but in another fragment.

Comment: This should work. Also, show your click listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need set orientation for Linearlayout otherwise it will host only one child

through programatically

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

or

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

And through XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/selectedTeamFrag"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    ....
    .... >
 ...
 ...
</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/selectedTeamFrag"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    ....
    .... >
 ...
 ...
</LinearLayout>
```

find below sample Activity code for Horizontal orientation

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/selectedTeamFrag"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.selectedTeamFrag);

        for (int count=0; count < 10 ; count++) {
            Button button1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
            button1.setText("B:"+count);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams x = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            button1.setLayoutParams(x);
            ll.addView(button1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output : -

[image]

Comment: Super! Many thanks! It is working :) I thought it is emught to set orientation in XML.

Comment: Hmmm, it is working only for `ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);` but still not working for HORIZONTAL ;(

Comment: It depends upon your button number if you want to add multiple button, then wrap LinearLayout inside HorizontalScrollView in XML

Comment: But if my Layout (where I added butons) is enough (width) to display 3 buttons? I want to add max 5 buttons (20dp).

Comment: I also added sample code, and make sure your LinearLayout width should be wrap_content or match_parent

Comment: Great Job! Thanks a lot! Please tell me one more thing, why it dosnt work witohut HorizontalScrollView for horizontal, and it works for without i.e VetricalScrollView for vertical?